# Pulseaudio uses Arozzi Sfera microphone as the default sink regardless of settings. How to diagnose or fix?

Tags: pulseaudio, 22.04

I have an Arozzi Sfera tabletop microphone. It has a headphone jack in the back, for what I presume is a monitor.

When the microphone is attached, I can see various audio output devices listed in the "Sound" tab of my settings view, including my bluetooth headphones, the HDMI connection to a display, and the microphone. When I select any output device and use the "test" function, the audio gets directed to the microphone's headphone jack.

I have attempted to run `pulseaudio -k` and `systemctl --user restart pulseaudio.service` when the problem manifests, to no avail.

The pulseaudio service status looks like this:

```
● pulseaudio.service - Sound Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pulseaudio.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-11-09 17:04:12 EET; 17min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pulseaudio.socket
   Main PID: 7052 (pulseaudio)
      Tasks: 8 (limit: 19009)
     Memory: 9.8M
        CPU: 9.083s
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pulseaudio.service
             └─7052 /usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=journal

marras 09 17:04:12 haem-desktop systemd[2192]: Starting Sound Service...
marras 09 17:04:12 haem-desktop pulseaudio[7052]: Failed to open cookie file '/home/haem/.config/pulse/cookie': Tiedostoa tai hakemistoa ei ole
marras 09 17:04:12 haem-desktop pulseaudio[7052]: Failed to load authentication key '/home/haem/.config/pulse/cookie': Tiedostoa tai hakemistoa ei ole
marras 09 17:04:12 haem-desktop pulseaudio[7052]: Module "module-udev-detect" should be loaded once at most. Refusing to load.
marras 09 17:04:12 haem-desktop systemd[2192]: Started Sound Service.
marras 09 17:04:12 haem-desktop pulseaudio[7052]: Could not find org.bluez.BatteryProviderManager1.RegisterBatteryProvider(), is bluetoothd started with experimental features enabled (-E flag)?
marras 09 17:04:38 haem-desktop pulseaudio[7052]: Transport Acquire() failed for transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_2C_4D_79_40_C5_3B/sep1/fd2 (Input/output error)
marras 09 17:05:02 haem-desktop pulseaudio[7052]: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get /org/bluez/hci0/dev_2C_4D_79_40_C5_3B/sep1/fd3 Volume failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such property 'Vo>
marras 09 17:05:02 haem-desktop pulseaudio[7052]: Battery Level: 100%
marras 09 17:05:02 haem-desktop pulseaudio[7052]: Dock Status: undocked
```

Unplugging the microphone and plugging it back in seems to occasionally fix the issue. When the issue is fixed, the status looks like

```
marras 09 17:04:12 haem-desktop pulseaudio[7052]: Failed to load authentication key '/home/haem/.config/pulse/cookie': Tiedostoa tai hakemistoa ei ole
marras 09 17:04:12 haem-desktop pulseaudio[7052]: Module "module-udev-detect" should be loaded once at most. Refusing to load.
marras 09 17:04:12 haem-desktop systemd[2192]: Started Sound Service.
marras 09 17:04:12 haem-desktop pulseaudio[7052]: Could not find org.bluez.BatteryProviderManager1.RegisterBatteryProvider(), is bluetoothd started with experimental features enabled (-E flag)?
marras 09 17:04:38 haem-desktop pulseaudio[7052]: Transport Acquire() failed for transport /org/bluez/hci0/dev_2C_4D_79_40_C5_3B/sep1/fd2 (Input/output error)
marras 09 17:05:02 haem-desktop pulseaudio[7052]: org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties.Get /org/bluez/hci0/dev_2C_4D_79_40_C5_3B/sep1/fd3 Volume failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs: No such property 'Vo>
marras 09 17:05:02 haem-desktop pulseaudio[7052]: Battery Level: 100%
marras 09 17:05:02 haem-desktop pulseaudio[7052]: Dock Status: undocked
marras 09 17:22:24 haem-desktop pulseaudio[7052]: Got POLLNVAL from ALSA
marras 09 17:22:24 haem-desktop pulseaudio[7052]: Error opening PCM device hw:1: Tiedostoa tai hakemistoa ei ole
```

"Tiedostoa tai hakemistoa ei ole" means "no such file or directory". I have checked that the folder `/haem/.config/pulse/` exists.

Searching the output of `pactl list` for the word "Arozzi" gives me this:

```
Module #8
    Name: module-alsa-card
    Argument: device_id="1" name="usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Arozzi_Sfera_Microphone-00" card_name="alsa_card.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Arozzi_Sfera_Microphone-00" namereg_fail=false tsched=yes fixed_latency_range=no ignore_dB=no deferred_volume=yes use_ucm=yes avoid_resampling=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"
    Usage counter: 0
    Properties:
        module.author = "Lennart Poettering"
        module.description = "ALSA Card"
        module.version = "15.99.1"

...

Sink #1
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Arozzi_Sfera_Microphone-00.iec958-stereo
    Description: Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A) Digitaalinen stereo (IEC958)
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 8
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    Monitor Source: alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Arozzi_Sfera_Microphone-00.iec958-stereo.monitor
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY SET_FORMATS 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "Arozzi Sfera Microphone"
        alsa.long_card_name = "C-Media Electronics Inc. Arozzi Sfera Microphone at usb-0000:00:14.0-4, full sp"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Arozzi_Sfera_Microphone-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "0d8c"
        device.vendor.name = "C-Media Electronics, Inc."
        device.product.id = "0014"
        device.product.name = "Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A)"
        device.serial = "C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Arozzi_Sfera_Microphone"
        device.form_factor = "microphone"
        device.string = "iec958:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "iec958-stereo"
        device.profile.description = "Digitaalinen stereo (IEC958)"
        device.description = "Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A) Digitaalinen stereo (IEC958)"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone-usb"
    Ports:
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (type: SPDIF, priority: 0, availability unknown)
    Active Port: iec958-stereo-output
    Formats:
        pcm

Source #1
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Arozzi_Sfera_Microphone-00.iec958-stereo.monitor
    Description: Monitor of Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A) Digitaalinen stereo (IEC958)
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
    Channel Map: front-left,front-right
    Owner Module: 8
    Mute: no
    Volume: front-left: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB,   front-right: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    Base Volume: 65536 / 100% / 0,00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: alsa_output.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Arozzi_Sfera_Microphone-00.iec958-stereo
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        device.description = "Monitor of Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A) Digitaalinen stereo (IEC958)"
        device.class = "monitor"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "Arozzi Sfera Microphone"
        alsa.long_card_name = "C-Media Electronics Inc. Arozzi Sfera Microphone at usb-0000:00:14.0-4, full sp"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Arozzi_Sfera_Microphone-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "0d8c"
        device.vendor.name = "C-Media Electronics, Inc."
        device.product.id = "0014"
        device.product.name = "Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A)"
        device.serial = "C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Arozzi_Sfera_Microphone"
        device.form_factor = "microphone"
        device.string = "1"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone-usb"
    Formats:
        pcm

...
Source #2
    State: SUSPENDED
    Name: alsa_input.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Arozzi_Sfera_Microphone-00.mono-fallback
    Description: Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A) Mono
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Sample Specification: s16le 1ch 44100Hz
    Channel Map: mono
    Owner Module: 8
    Mute: no
    Volume: mono: 48211 /  74% / -8,00 dB
            balance 0,00
    Base Volume: 27111 /  41% / -23,00 dB
    Monitor of Sink: n/a
    Latency: 0 usec, configured 0 usec
    Flags: HARDWARE HW_MUTE_CTRL HW_VOLUME_CTRL DECIBEL_VOLUME LATENCY 
    Properties:
        alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
        device.api = "alsa"
        device.class = "sound"
        alsa.class = "generic"
        alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
        alsa.name = "USB Audio"
        alsa.id = "USB Audio"
        alsa.subdevice = "0"
        alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
        alsa.device = "0"
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "Arozzi Sfera Microphone"
        alsa.long_card_name = "C-Media Electronics Inc. Arozzi Sfera Microphone at usb-0000:00:14.0-4, full sp"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Arozzi_Sfera_Microphone-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "0d8c"
        device.vendor.name = "C-Media Electronics, Inc."
        device.product.id = "0014"
        device.product.name = "Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A)"
        device.serial = "C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Arozzi_Sfera_Microphone"
        device.form_factor = "microphone"
        device.string = "hw:1"
        device.buffering.buffer_size = "176400"
        device.buffering.fragment_size = "88200"
        device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
        device.profile.name = "mono-fallback"
        device.profile.description = "Mono"
        device.description = "Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A) Mono"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone-usb"
    Ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, availability unknown)
    Active Port: analog-input-mic
    Formats:
        pcm

...
Card #1
    Name: alsa_card.usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Arozzi_Sfera_Microphone-00
    Driver: module-alsa-card.c
    Owner Module: 8
    Properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "Arozzi Sfera Microphone"
        alsa.long_card_name = "C-Media Electronics Inc. Arozzi Sfera Microphone at usb-0000:00:14.0-4, full sp"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:14.0-usb-0:4:1.0"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-4/1-4:1.0/sound/card1"
        udev.id = "usb-C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Arozzi_Sfera_Microphone-00"
        device.bus = "usb"
        device.vendor.id = "0d8c"
        device.vendor.name = "C-Media Electronics, Inc."
        device.product.id = "0014"
        device.product.name = "Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A)"
        device.serial = "C-Media_Electronics_Inc._Arozzi_Sfera_Microphone"
        device.form_factor = "microphone"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "Audio Adapter (Unitek Y-247A)"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone-usb"
    Profiles:
        input:mono-fallback: Mono Sisääntulo (sinks: 0, sources: 1, priority: 1, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo: Analoginen stereo Ulostulo (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 6500, available: yes)
        output:analog-stereo+input:mono-fallback: Analoginen stereo Ulostulo + Mono Sisääntulo (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 6501, available: yes)
        output:iec958-stereo: Digitaalinen stereo (IEC958) Ulostulo (sinks: 1, sources: 0, priority: 5500, available: yes)
        output:iec958-stereo+input:mono-fallback: Digitaalinen stereo (IEC958) Ulostulo + Mono Sisääntulo (sinks: 1, sources: 1, priority: 5501, available: yes)
        off: Poissa (sinks: 0, sources: 0, priority: 0, available: yes)
    Active Profile: output:iec958-stereo+input:mono-fallback
    Ports:
        analog-input-mic: Microphone (type: Mic, priority: 8700, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Properties:
                device.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
            Part of profile(s): input:mono-fallback, output:analog-stereo+input:mono-fallback, output:iec958-stereo+input:mono-fallback
        analog-output: Analog Output (type: Analogue, priority: 9900, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Part of profile(s): output:analog-stereo, output:analog-stereo+input:mono-fallback
        iec958-stereo-output: Digital Output (S/PDIF) (type: SPDIF, priority: 0, latency offset: 0 usec, availability unknown)
            Part of profile(s): output:iec958-stereo, output:iec958-stereo+input:mono-fallback
```

Unloading the alsa-card module by number (`pactl unload-module 8` in this case) also disables the microphone as an input.

`pactl info` tells me that the default sink is `bluez_sink.2C_4D_79_40_C5_3B.a2dp_sink`. This changes when I change audio output from the settings.

A possibly related issue is that, when I disconnect and reconnect the microphone, I can see the microphone as the "default" output in my audio settings.

Another observation; when I explicitly set the audio sink in an application's settings, e.g. in the Discord desktop app, that works. It seems that it is only the default sink and/or gnome that exhibits this behavior.

Around the end of March this year, this behavior seems to have become constant. I know it worked correctly on the 30th. The only fix I have is to unplug the microphone.

I would like to know how to fix this. Failing that, I would like to know how to diagnose this to a point that I can make a bug report to the correct party.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found the solution. Using `pavucontrol`, I found the audio profile of the microphone, and the profile configured for it was "Digital stereo output+mono input", which was confusing pulseaudio. I believe this is the `iec958-stereo+input` output profile.

Changing this to just "mono input", which I believe to be `mono-fallback`, fixed the issue.